# How to add image views to custom annotation view keep pin image on screen and take touches from it?

Tags: ios, mapkit, mkannotation, mkannotationview, mkpinannotationview

I have a mapview with pins that show location of photo (coordinates are taken from CoreData) and I need to show photo when pin is selected (using its URL and AFNetworking).

I need to save **both** pin image **and** photo image when pin is selected.

If next pin is selected the previous pin is deselected so I remove photo from screen and add another photo of the corresponding pin.

Here is an image to show what particularly I need:

[image]

So the pin is on screen and the Photo is on screen.

Problems:

1. This task is for iPhone so usage of popover is not available.
2. I need to keep **both** image of pin and photo, not an image instead of pin. That's why  I  cannot simply use property 'image' of MKPinAnnotationView class - it sets image 
   **instead**  of pin.
3. MK has some private classes for its views so using search over touches is a problem.

Solution for the first and second problem:
I've made a custom class of MKPinAnnotationView which is responsible for adding imageView to MKPinAnnotationView to keep both pin image and photo on screen.

```
#import "PSMKPinAnnotationView.h"
//my custom annotations, I keep URLs and coordinates of photos   there.
#import "PSMapAnnonation.h" 
#import "UIImageView+AFNetworking.h" //to display images by URL

@interface PSMKPinAnnotationView ()

@property (nonatomic, strong) UIImageView *imageViewForAnnotaion;

//property in header is:
//@property (nonatomic, getter = isDetailViewHidden) BOOL detailViewHidden;
@end

@implementation PSMKPinAnnotationView

- (BOOL)validAnnotation
{
 return  [self.annotation isKindOfClass:[PSMapAnnonation class]]; 
}


- (void)setDetailViewHidden:(BOOL)detailViewHidden
{

//draw image in custom view
if (detailViewHidden==NO)
{
    if ([self validAnnotation])
    {
        self.annotation=(PSMapAnnonation*)self.annotation;
        CGRect rect=CGRectMake(0, -35, 30, 30);  // y=-35 to make correct offset

        self.imageViewForAnnotaion = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:rect];

        [self.imageViewForAnnotaion setImageWithURL: 
        [(PSMapAnnonation*)self.annotation    imageURL]];

        [self setClipsToBounds:NO];
        [self addSubview:self.imageViewForAnnotaion];
    }

 }

 else if (detailViewHidden==YES)
 {
    if ([self validAnnotation])
    {
        [self.imageViewForAnnotaion removeFromSuperview]];
    }
 }

}
```

In ViewController where my mapview is in methods of mapView I'm doing this:

```
- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView didSelectAnnotationView:(PSMKPinAnnotationView   
*)view
{
if ([view.annotation isKindOfClass:[MKUserLocation class ]]) return;

view.detailViewHidden=NO;
}

-(void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView didDeselectAnnotationView:(MKAnnotationView *)view

{

if (![view isKindOfClass:[PSMKPinAnnotationView class]]) {
return; //blue point which describes currecnt user position is a view pin too
        //and in case of being selected without this check app will crash.  
}

PSMKPinAnnotationView *customAnnotationView=(PSMKPinAnnotationView*)view;
[customAnnotationView setDetailViewHidden:YES];

}
```

So, I've made solution for first two problems:

The result is this:

[image]

But the third problem was detected during search over touched views om MKMapView

```
#pragma mark - Touches
- (void) touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event 
{

    NSLog(@"touch");
    UITouch *touch = [[event allTouches] anyObject];
    CGPoint touchLocation = [touch locationInView:self.mapView];

    for (UIView *view in self.mapView.subviews)
    {
      if ([view isKindOfClass:[PSMKPinAnnotationView class]] &&
        CGRectContainsPoint(view.frame, touchLocation))
     {
        NSLog(@"%@",[view class]);
    }


    NSLog(@"%@",[view class]);
   }
 }
```

Logs show me some Apple's private classes:

```
- 2014-06-19  11:00:45.428 PhotoShare[881:60b] touch
- 2014-06-19 11:00:45.428  PhotoShare[881:60b] UIView
- 2014-06-19 11:00:45.428  PhotoShare[881:60b] MKAttributionLabel
- 2014-06-19 11:01:47.574  PhotoShare[881:60b] touch
- 2014-06-19 11:01:47.575  PhotoShare[881:60b] UIView
- 2014-06-19 11:01:47.575  PhotoShare[881:60b] MKAttributionLabel
```

**In case of touch on my photo (its image view) my Custom class for view is not detected and some MKAttributionLabel and UIView are shown**

- Is there any simple solution to do this stuff?
- How to connect touches to added imageView and to find them in views? 
  Logs showed me that MapKit adds some its own views like
  MKAttributionLabel(Apple's private classes)?